# How to convert an mp3/wave audio file to a Jmathstudio vector in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, matlab, vector, mp3

i am building an application that analyses an audio and report a specific an output afterwards. first of all, the functions that carries out the audio analyses was simulated on Matlab to make sure the output is fine. Then, JMathstudio library was used to implement the functions used in Matlab in Android Studio.

i want to test the code, but the problem is that when i import an MP3/wave audio file, i could not figure how to convert them to a JMathStudio vector, which corresponds to this library:

```
import org.JMathStudio.DataStructure.Vector.Vector;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use some third party library to read Mp3/Wave audio file and get buffer from it. Once you have buffer data you can create a float array and use this array to create an instance of Vector in jmathstudio.

By default JmathStudio does not support codec for reading Mp3/wave on android platform.